# Angular + Cypress w/ Cucumber - where is Cypress.json?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, cucumber, cypress

We're migrating from Protractor to Cypress with Cucumber (via cypress-cucumber-preprocessor). All the Angular documentation I can find for implementing this, such as https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-run-cypress-cucumber-test , all mention an auto generated `cypress.json` file at my project root. Cypress does successfully run in my project, but there is no `cypress.json` file at my project root or anywhere else. There is a `cypress.config.ts`, however.

Is `cypress.json` deprecated in the newest versions in Angular and, if so, what is its replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cypress.json` is deprecated in the newest major release of Cypress, v10+.

The best approach might be to initially install Cypress v9.7.0, then get some smoke tests running, then upgrade to Cypress v10.0.3 and let Cypress migrate for you.

There may be some catch-up period for Angular, but the above steps gives you a path. (Same applies for cypress-cucumber-preprocessor).